# Horizontal ListView.builder overflow width bound when scroll

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to use ListView.builder to display a horizontal list in a Stack but am encountering this weird bug when scrolling ListView if I set `itemCount: 10`. If I set `itemCount: 20` the ListView scrolls like normal.

I have tested in the emulator (Galaxy Nexus 720x1280 android 5.0) and on a real device (Nokia 7 plus, android 9.0). How can I fix this?

```
class BugPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              left: 20.0,
              right: 20.0,
              height: 60.0,
              bottom: 70.0,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: 10, // Overflow when scroll.
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 3.0,
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            width: 40.0,
                            height: 40.0,
                            color: Colors.red,
                            child: Center(child: Text("$index")),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: new Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Expected output:

[image]

Actual output:

[image]

And a [video of the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFQRYqEAOY4)

Comment: can you add error logs? I'm not getting any issue with this code

Comment: @AmolG Console log doesn't show any errors, just listview UI overflow max width bound when scrolling in my emulator. Please watch the new [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFQRYqEAOY4) I uploaded for more information.

Comment: The only change that you are making to go from image 1 to image 2 is `itemCount: 10` to `itemCount: 20`? Is there any other change between the two codes?

Comment: @KeertiPurswani Yes, the bugged code is what I embed in question with ```itemcount: 10```. If I set ```itemcount: 20``` listview work like normal.

Comment: i tried your code, it is not showing an overflow, with 10 or 20, can you please show how are you calling the `BugPage`

Comment: @SamiKanafani Really strange.
```void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Platter',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xFF356859),
        primaryColorDark: Color(0xFF37966F),
        accentColor: Color(0xFFFD5523),
      ),
      home: new BugPage(),
    );
  }```

Comment: @SamiKanafani I run this code in the emulator (Galaxy Nexus 720x1280 android 5.0) and the real device (Nokia 7 plus, android P), all show an overflow.

Comment: Try changing to Flexible instead of Expanded

Comment: @HarshBhikadia Change to Flexible still has an overflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like this bug appears in old flutter version after I updated to newest version everything is ok.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and run with bigger intemcount too without problems, but i have an advice, change the

`SizedBox(width: 10.0)`

for a padding around the button

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
  child: FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    onPressed: () {},
    child: new Icon(
      Icons.add,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
  )
)
```

Comment: Nice one! Worked for me